# How use a select in simple QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have a query by QueryOver In Nhibernate 3.1

```
   var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>()
           .Where(p => p.Code == code);
           .Select(p => p.Name,p => p.Code);


   return q.SingleOrDefault();
```

This query without select is correct, but with select has a runtime error by this message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyNameSpace.Domain.Entities.Person'. How can i select some field of Person?

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell NHibernate explicitly what is the type of your return data since you choose to select some specific properties of your original entity `p.Name`,`P.Code` these properties must by returned as of a new type of entity so the new type would be a new `object`

```
 var query = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>()
                 .Where(p => p.Code == code)
                 .Select(
                     p => p.Name,
                     p => p.Code
                 )
                 .List<object>();
```

this will solve your problem

or if you defined a new entity to hold the new return data as following :

```
public newPeople
{
     public Id { get; set; }
     public Nam { get; set; }
}
```

you can write it like that:

```
 var query = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>()
                 .Where(p => p.Code == code)
                 .Select(
                     p => p.Name,
                     p => p.Code
                 )
                 .Select( list =>
                    new newPeople()
                    {
                          Id = (int) list[0],
                          Name = (string) list[1]
                    })
                 .ToList<newPeople>();
```

Comment: I do it, But this has a runtime error by this message: 
Could not determine member from new Person(p.Id) {Code = p.Code, Name = p.Name} 
My changed code is :
 var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>()
     .Where(p => p.IdentificationCode == identificationCode)
     .Select( p => new Person(p.Id) { Code=p.Code, Name = p.Name });

 return q.SingleOrDefault<Person>();

Comment: Yeah, thats right thats becourse this part `.Select(p=> new Person(p.Id)` what do you want to select by this query, Did you have a predefined `Person` entity that you want to select your data to if so i didn't written like that try the way i show you in my answer and did you try my answer and did it work the way i wrote it?

Comment: I tested your codealready, But it has 3 build error
On "list" word: error by this Message:
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyNamespace.Domain.Entities.Person,object>>[]' because it is not a delegate type

      and On "list[0]" and "list[1]"  words: error by this Message:
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'MyNamespace.Domain.Entities.Person